# Disadvantages after Disabling viewstate for aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have read some articles on viewstate, but didn't find exactly what I wanted.

I have a simple aspx page on which I have a textbox and a button control.

If I disable the viewstate for the whole page at design time -> run the application -> then across postbacks after clicking the button, 
what difference would I see on my page ?
I just want to see the difference between two cases i.e. viewstate enabled and viewstate disabled.

Can you please explain me **with example** ?

Comment: The viewstate is the tentative of Microsoft to make the web statefull. For example, if you add validation to your simple webform when you submit the page and the validation fails your page is rendered once again possibly with an error message. If you don't use viewstate your textbox will lose the value entered in it while it will still be there with viewstate activated. There are plenty of resources out there explaining this extensively, [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) for example is a good one. why don't you just try to build an example yourself ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have done with example having a page with textbox and button on it. but even with viewstate disabled for page, the textbox retains its value after postback. During my search, i found that populating controls with their values i.e. textbox in this case, is not the task of viewstate. that's why I wanted to see the difference caused by disabling viewstate.